# how to distinguish syncdb from runserver in models initialization?

Tags: django, model

I would like to make some initializations on my tables when I use ./manage.py runserver

As I need metaclasses for initialization, is is run in both syncdb and runserver.

The problem, is that the tables does not exist yet when I run ./manage.py syncdb.
So I want to test when I am not in "syncdb" mode :

Does it exist a way to test whether a model is read for syncdb or for runserver ?

In my models, I would like to do something like :

```
if not is_in_syncdb_mode():
    do_model_auto_prefill_before_runserver()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `post_syncdb` signal: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-syncdb